# I only can connect to my nginx server from local computer

Tags: django, nginx

First of all, please excuse my low-level English.
I'm not native English speaker..
but I'll try to explain well as far as possible.

I really have no idea about this situation.
I thought that it's iptables problem.. but it seems not.

I'm getting a server hosting(CentOS).
I installed Nginx + Django and nginx uses 8080 port.
A domain is connected to the server.

When I executed "wget [domain]:8080/[app name]/" in the server,
it works.
Of course, "wget 127.0.0.1:8080/[app name]/" has no problem.
(wget [server ip]:8080/[app name]/, either)

However, from other computers, connecting failed.

I checked my firewall setting.
I executed these commands.

```
 iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
 iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 8080 -j ACCEPT
 iptables -A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
 /etc/init.d/iptables restart
```

I don't really understand all options of commands and I think there were useless commands, but I just tried all googled iptables settings.

But still I cannot connect to my server.
What should I check, first?

I don't know if this is important, but I am adding to this post.
On 80 port, an apache server is running.
It works fine, I can connect to apache from other computers.
There is DB connecting issue, (PHP to MySQL) but I think that it is just PHP coding bug.

Thank you for reading this question.

Comment: Can you telnet from a remote machine to your server `telnet <serverip> 8080`?

Comment: @RickyA `telnet [ip] 8080
Trying [ip]...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: No route to host`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to stop my firewall, and It worked.
So the problem is on my iptables setting.
I had allowed 8080 port, but I think there was a mistake on the settings. I regret that I didn't read and study settings carefully.
I flushed all setting, and restart server. All looks fine.